# Django not seeing Users in database?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-generic-views

I have a database and have the admin interface enabled. When I go to the admin interface and click on 'Users' there is one user whose username is `ayman`. I am following a tutorial done in a book called 'Packt Publishing, Learning Website Development with Django'. Now, in my `urls.py`, this is what I have.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', main_page),
    url(r'^user/(\w+)/$', user_page), 
)
```

In my `views.py`, this is my `user_page`

```
def user_page(request, username):

    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    except:
        raise Http404(username +' not found.')

    bookmarks = user.bookmark_set.all()
    variables = {
        'username': username,
        'bookmarks': bookmarks
    }

    return render(request, 'user_page.html', variables)
```

I am using the generic `User` view to manage my users. When I go into the terminal and do

```
$python manage.py shell
```

and do

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> from bookmarks.models import *
>>> user = User.objects.get(id=1)
>>> user
<User: ayman>
>>> user.username
u'ayman'
```

as you can see, the username `ayman` Does exist. Now, going back to the URLs and the `user_page` view. In my web browser, I went to

```
127.0.0.1/user/ayman/
```

The `urls.py` should capture `ayman` and pass it as a parameter to `user_page`, right? It does, but the `user_page` view keeps raising the 404 error and it says `ayman not found`. So the `username` parameter in `user_page` is in fact `ayman` but it keeps failing the

```
user = User.objects.get(username=username)
```

even though `ayman` is a username in my database. Any idea why?

Comment: You are using a bare `except`. If you change that to `except User.DoesNotExist:`, do you get a traceback?

Comment: @sk1p it gives a NameError at /user/ayman/ and says that global name 'User' is not defined.

Comment: Then you need to do `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`

Comment: This is btw a schoolbook example of why never to use `except` without specifying the error class

Comment: @SteinarLima Ah okay perfect, that fixed it. Thanks and thank you sk1p. One of you can leave that as the answer and I will accept that.

Comment: @sk1p spotted it, so he should have the honour :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a bare `except` clause, try `except User.DoesNotExist`. The bare `except` masks the real error, the missing import. Btw. there is also a shortcut for this:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
# ...
user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
```

The first argument is the model or a queryset, the following are all passed as keyword arguments to `queryset.get()`